# Which method of NSURLConnectionDataDelegate will be summoned in case of HTTP 500 Internal server error?

Tags: objective-c

Which method of NSURLConnectionDataDelegate will be  summoned  in case of HTTP 500 Internal server error?

Answer (score 0):

General error can capture by didFailWithError method:

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        //Your code to handle connection errors
    }
```

but for

> 404 "Not Found"

or

> 500 "Internal Server Error"

should able to capture inside `didReceiveResponse` method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(statusCode)])
    {
        int statusCode = [((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response) statusCode];
        if (statusCode == 500)
        {
            [connection cancel];  // stop connecting; no more delegate messages
            NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse statusCode with %i", statusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 500 Internal Server Error

A generic error message, given when an unexpected condition was encountered and no more specific message is suitable. Source of this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes and
 https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html

So need to check on server side. It's not your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
```

will be called in case of HTTP 500 Internal server error.

You can check response status and handle inside:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
```